# Two routers or one router and WAP?

Tags: networking, wifi, infrastructure

I have an ADSL2 router/modem with internet access and I want to access 3 IP cameras (3 network clients) over wireless behind that router from the internet. My problem is that the ADSL2 router/modem does *not* support wireless.
Now, I have the following two options:

1. Connecting a wireless router behind the ADSL router. This would look like this:

   [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gt6NL.png]

   My wireless router has LAN ports so the switch would be redundant.

   or,
2. A Wireless Access Point (WAP), connected to the router (if technically possible).

**Which is the best alternative?** ***Why?***

Important factors:

- Low complexity
- Ease-of-configuration

The economical factor doesn't play an important role.

Many thanks in advance,
Kenny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the wireless router, you should just use that. You'll want to hook it up differently in order to avoid a double NAT situation. Disable DHCP on the wireless router. Assign it an internal IP address that is valid on your DSL router. Then hook up the wireless router to the DSL router using the LAN ports on each device. This will make it act just like a WAP.

If you don't already have either device, you might as well buy the WAP as that will be easier to setup.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer Jason. I have assigned static IPs to my cameras, turned off DHCP in my wireless router, connected the wireless router to the wired router with a LAN cable(from the WAN port to one of the wired router's LAN ports), have set a static IP for WAN pointing to the wired router.
When I connect to the wireless router I can succesfully ping the wired router, but I don't have internet access. Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: You need to connect the LAN port on the wireless router to a LAN port on the wired router. The WAN port on the wireless router will not be used. Also, set the static IP on the LAN side of the wireless router, not the WAN side. The cameras also need to have IPs that are valid on the wired router